# How can I use Autowired annotation in ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, autowired, spring-data-redis

I want to use `@Autowired` for `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` in `springboot`

```
public class RequestResponseHandlerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private localService localService;

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";


    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        ClientHttpResponse response = null;
        ------
        ------
        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your case. Also refer https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/clienthttprequestinterceptor/

Comment: Want to do some preprocessing by access instance of redistemplate and my local service.

Comment: can you share chunks of code where you want to use ClientHttpRequestInterceptor